# How often is Chris Evans wearing a wig as Captain America?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america

Steve Rogers' hair varies throughout the Marvel Cinematic Universe films. In *Captain America: The First Avenger* and *The Avengers*, it seems very blonde and wavy. In later films like *The Winter Soldier*, his hair seems spikier and more of a dirty blonde. My question is: in what MCU films is Chris Evans wearing a wig and in what films is it just his hair styled differently?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212220/58193) and [related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/222126/58193).

Comment: They basically did the same thing with him as they did with Thor - started out with the more comic-accurate look and then gradually changed it to match the actor's actual hair color and style.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I can tell, the only times Evans wore a hairpiece while filming the MCU films were during the shawarma scene at the end of the first Avengers movie, since it was filmed later and he'd already had to change his hairstyle for filming *Snowpiercer* (they also had to use prosthetics to hide his facial hair, which is why Cap isn't eating), and when filming his last scenes in *Endgame* where he wore it over a bald cap as discussed (and shown) [here](https://screenrant.com/avengers-shawarma-scene-captain-america-chris-evans-eating/) and [here](https://www.cbr.com/chris-evans-bald-steve-rogers-avengers-endgame/).

Comment: Good answer. But can you add references to it if possible? It'll make the answer more precise and trustworthy :)

Comment: Were there actually prosthetics?  I recall in that scene he just had his head turned to the side and resting on his fist to cover up the mustache.  Given how much of a throwaway scene that was, it seems like a fancy prosthetic would be a bit excessive.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It seems it was pretty much a rubber jawline quickly glued in place, which left Evans unable to open his mouth during the scene and didn't look very good close-up. Nothing really fancy.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman prosthetics and hand to cover it up. See [this related Q/A](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222127/58193).

Answer (score 8):

He doesn’t wear a wig at all for the majority of the films, it’s all his own hair albeit dyed at times, certainly so in the earlier films, because he has quite dark hair. You can see this from some of the real life photos of the actor, for example, the premieres for *Captain America: The First Avenger*, *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* and *Avengers: Endgame*.

[image: Chris Evans wearing glasses with longish hair spiked up] [image: Chris Evans with dark styled hair and a beard] [image: Chris Evans again with dark styles hair and a beard]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

The only times he seems to wear a wig are in the [shawarma scene in *The Avengers*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222127/58193) because he’d cut his hair and grown a beard for *Snowpiercer* which also meant he had to wear a prosthetic.

He also wears a [bald cap in the final scenes of *Avengers: Endgame*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212220/58193). Of course this is for

> Old Steve as he’d grown old with Peggy.[image: Side by side image of Chris with his makeup and bald cap on and his body double]

Lastly, whilst you can’t really find evidence that actors use their real hair in the majority of cases, for obvious reasons, I have found an interview of him talking about growing his beard. Or several to be honest after it went viral.

> “Well that’s good. That’s good, because I like it too,” said the 36-year-old star. “I mean, I usually live my life with a beard. I’m not a huge fan of shaving, and it just provides a little bit of anonymity at times… I was really excited that the Russo’s and Marvel were willing to kinda give that look a shot.”
>
> <sub>[ET Canada, Chris Evans Likes Captain America’s Beard Too: ‘I’m Not A Huge Fan Of Shaving’](https://etcanada.com/news/289335/chris-evans-likes-captain-americas-beard-too-im-not-a-huge-fan-of-shaving/)</sub>